# Maven spring sample project unable to build

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

> [ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1] [ERROR]
>   [ERROR]   The project com.example.angularjs:demo:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
>   (C:\Users\vvk\Downloads\demo\pom.xml) has 1 error [ERROR]
>   Non-resolvable parent POM for
>   com.example.angularjs:demo:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not transfer artifact
>   org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:1.5.3.RELEASE
>   from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2):
>   sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target and
>   'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM @ line 14, column 10 ->
>   [Help 2] [ERROR]

I am getting the above error when trying to run a simple demo project.

Here is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.charter.angularjs</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>


    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

         <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Comment: Why do you need this `<relativePath/>` in `parent` element? Remove this line and all should works fine.

Comment: The relativePath has nothing to do with the error message. The problem is related to JDK version based on SSL connection...

Answer (score 0):

Are you running on Java 7, if so then there is a regression openjdk relating to  SSL https://github.com/docker-library/openjdk/issues/117

Suggested fix, update to Java 8.